# Как правильно уменьшить ширину span'а?

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, bootstrap, span, вёрстка, css

Bootstrap 2.3.2

Как правильно уменьшить ширину span'а? Например, есть span8, я хочу, чтобы он был поуже, но не настолько узкий, как span7. Для примера на картинке span8 ofset2, мне нужно, чтобы зеленый div был уже, чем красная надпись и синяя кнопка.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать сетку не 12 колонок, а 18 или 24. По [этой ссылке](http://bootstrap.site-style.by/2.3.2/customize.html) ещё работает кастомайзер для bootstrap 2. Например, при 24 колонках `span8 ofset2` станет `span16 ofset4`, а стиль `span15` будет как `span7.5` в 12-колоночном макете.

Answer (score 1):

```
.span12 {
  width: 940px;
}

.span11 {
  width: 860px;
}

.span10 {
  width: 780px;
}

.span9 {
  width: 700px;
}

.span8 {
  width: 620px;
}

.span7 {
  width: 540px;
}

.span6 {
  width: 460px;
}

.span5 {
  width: 380px;
}

.span4 {
  width: 300px;
}

.span3 {
  width: 220px;
}

.span2 {
  width: 140px;
}

.span1 {
  width: 60px;
}
```